# How to make printf properly print a strtok of a user input argv in C

Tags: c, terminal

I am able to use this to print my default string, but when I go to print a user input it does not work--instead I get some random characters and symbols back

```
int i=0;
char* tok=strtok(defaultString," ");
while(tok!=NULL){
         i++;
         if (i==defaultInd){
             printf("%s \n", tok);
             break;             
         }
         tok=strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

I believe that there is some issue with accessing memory or something store in a memory that I haven't actually initialized yet, but when I try to use

```
char* tok=(char *)malloc(strlen(strtok(sent, " ")+1));
```

it just stops printing things period.

My work around had been to print argv using a for loop but I still don't know what the actual problem is.

Here is what I have to print the user input

```
char* tok=strtok(argv," ");
    while(tok!=NULL){
         printf("%s\n", tok);
         tok=strtok(NULL," ");
    }
```

I get back a series of symbols (alphanumeric, greek, etc) instead of the string I input

Comment: Have you considered what type `argv` is? Have you checked the compiler warnings?

Comment: I deleted the [tag:ubuntu] tag.

Comment: I'm not actually getting any compiler warnings which is the strange thing. I know argv is a char** (I did try using char* as well) and I'm not using argv[] although changing it to that hasn't affected the code output

Comment: @KMM I put some remarks in my answer

Comment: to print the command line parameters:  `for( int 1; i<argc; i++ ) { printf( "%s\n", argv[i] ); }`  Note: command line parameters rarely ever contain spaces unless the parameter is enclosed in `"`s

Comment: Note: `argv[]` is an array of pointers, there are no spaces unless one of the pointers happens to contain a 0x20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
char* tok=(char *)malloc(strlen(strtok(sent, " ")+1));
```

you just allocate a piece of memory whose size depends on the result of *strtok*, but the result of *strtok* is *not* copied into the returned block of memory

---

```
char* tok=strtok(argv," ");
while(tok!=NULL){
     printf("%s\n", tok);
     tok=strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

If *argv* is the second argument of *main* that one is not a *char** but a *char***, so your call is wrong

What did you expect to do ? if it is to print the arguments or the program you have to do something like :

```
while (*++argv != 0)
  puts(*argv);
```

If you want to get each word from a group of words given in the first argument of the program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc == 2) {
    char* tok=strtok(argv[1]," ");

    while(tok!=NULL){
      printf("%s\n", tok);
      tok=strtok(NULL," ");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out "aze qsd wxc"
aze
qsd
wxc
```

As you see I have to use a string when I call *./a.out* else there are 3 argument and the first argument is just *aze*

---

In

```
int i=0;
char* tok=strtok(defaultString," ");
while(tok!=NULL){
         i++;
         if (i==defaultInd){
             printf("%s \n", tok);
             break;             
         }
         tok=strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

if *defaultString* is for instance "11 22 33" and *defaultInd* values 2 you will print *22*

but you do not said what are the value of these variables

Comment: In the first working code snipped I provide, I'm just trying to print a word at some defaultIndex; in the not working code, I'm just trying to get it to print anything. I changed it to char** but am still getting the same nonsense outputs.

I added a line that sets tok=strtok(argv, " ") but that again doesn't change any outputs

I am just starting in C so have not yet encountered puts or gets altough I can see how your snippet is more efficient

Comment: @KMM your question is not clear, what is the not working code ? where and what did you changed from <not said> to `char **`. You need to give the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) else it is impossible for us to help you, we do not have a magic crystal ball

Comment: @KMM I edited my answer adding a new case, I cannot do more without more inputs from you

Answer (score 0):

```
char* tok = strtok(defaultString, " ");
    while (tok != NULL){
        myarg[count]=strdup(tok);
        count ++;
        printf("%s\n", tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please [edit] your answer and add some commentary as to how this will solve the question, and/or how it differs from previous answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22164906)